# Are A and A^T unitarily equivalent over a p-adic field?

Tags: linear-algebra, p-adic-groups

Let $E/F$ be a quadratic extension of p-adic field. Let $U=\{u\in GL_2(E): uu^*=1\}$ be the unitary group of rank 2.

My question is: given a matrix $A\in GL_2(E)$ can we find $u_1,u_2\in U$ such that
$A^T=u_1Au_2$, where $A^T$ is the transpose of A.

Comment: What does $u^{\ast}$ mean for a $p$-adic field?

Comment: Did you look a Kedlaya's book ?

Comment: @DenisSerre no. What is name of that book? Thanks.

Comment: @PaceNielsen $u^*$ means the conjugate transpose as in the complex/real field case. Here conjugate means the nontrivial Galois action for the field extension E/F.

Comment: @DenisSerre Do you mean the book "p-adic differential equation"? Before I thought this "elementary" linear algebra problem had a "elementary" solution. I never thought we need "p-adic differential equation" things. Unfortunately, I cannot find this book at the moment, and it is not in our library. Do we have an affirmative answer for this question?

Comment: Well, the field of differential equations begins with linear ones. Therefore, it needs a lot of linear algebra, and Kedlaya's book contains a thorough introduction to all kind of matrices with entries in $p$-adic fields.

Comment: @DenisSerre Does that book assume that the field is $\mathbb{C}_p$ rather than a (non-algebraically closed) local field? I think "differential" things might heavily depend on the field is algebraically closed. Anyway, thank you so much.

Comment: Here is one way to proceed.To have group actions,it is better to look at the equation $A^t=u_1Au_2^{-1}.$The first step is to check if it is true over an algebraic closure of $E$.If the answer is no, then you are done.If the answer is yes, you can study the corresponding Galois descent problem. If you set $G=\{(u_1,u_2) \mid u_1Au_2^{-1}=A\}$, then the question is: what is the kernel of $H^1(F, G)\to H^1(F,U)\times H^1(F,U)$ ? If you are lucky, it is trivial, and you are done.If not, you need to compute the cocycle corresponding to $A^t$ and decide if its class in $H^1(F,G)$ is trivial or not.

Comment: Maybe it's not the simplest way to proceed. However Galois cohomology of $U$ over $p$-adic fields is well-known. If $G$ can be identified with a nice algebraic group then, the map in cohomology may be easy to compute. 

However, before doing that, you might want to compare the characteristic polynomials of $A$ and $u_1Au_2^{-1}$. This would give you necessary conditions ofr the existence of $u_1$ and $u_2$.